# fopen() returns NULL, file exists in current directory

Tags: c, fopen

I can't make head or tail of this - I have a file `input1.txt` in my working directory, but I can't `fopen()` it.

**My directory structure (Xcode):**

[image]

**main():**

```
const char* fileName = "input1.txt";
if (argc > 1)
{
    fileName = argv[1];
}
printf("Opening file: %s\n", fileName);

clock_t timer = clock();

HashMap* map = hashMapNew(10);

// --- Concordance code begins here ---
// Be sure to free the word after you are done with it here.
FILE *in;
if ( (in = fopen(fileName, "r") ) == NULL ) {
    printf ("Can’t open %s for reading. %s\n", fileName, strerror(errno));
}
char* w = nextWord(in);
printf("%s",w);
```

**nextWord():**

```
char* nextWord(FILE* file)
{
    int maxLength = 16;
    int length = 0;
    char* word = malloc(sizeof(char) * maxLength);
    while (1)
    {
        char c = fgetc(file);
        if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') ||
            (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ||
            (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ||
            c == '\'')
        {
            if (length + 1 >= maxLength)
            {
                maxLength *= 2;
                word = realloc(word, maxLength);
            }
            word[length] = c;
            length++;
        }
        else if (length > 0 || c == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (length == 0)
    {
        free(word);
        return NULL;
    }
    word[length] = '\0';
    return word;
}
```

I get the error:

> Can’t open input1.txt for reading. No such file or directory

Why does this not work? The file definitely is there...

Comment: The "current" directory in an IDE may not always be what you think it is. Check project settings to see what the "current" directory is set to.  Also please edit your question to tell us what IDE you are using. You can of course always print it out inside the program to see what it is.

Comment: One thing you MUST fix, you check if the `fopen()` call succeeded and that's great but you go on anywat trying to read from it, doesn't that look incorrect to you?

Comment: Provide the full path and try opening the file or do system(pwd) to get the working directory.

Comment: I'm using Xcode - Printing the working directory says: `/Users/tomeldridge/Desktop/assignment6/build/Debug`

Comment: Check if your file input1.txt gets copied to the Debug directory! If not, you have found the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode, your project "folders" are better referred to as "groups," that may or may not refer to actual folders on the disk.  The group directory hierarchy is stored in your project settings and does not necessarily correspond to your filesystem hierarchy (think symlinks).  Try right-clicking on one of the files in question, and selecting "Show in Finder" to see its real location on disk.

If the input1.txt isn't actually in the same directory on disk as the calling function file, try moving it through Finder, and re-adding it to the project through Xcode (File-> "Add files to...").

Edit: I just found a tool to synchronize your group and file structures. [Take a look at synx](https://github.com/venmo/synx)